# How to perform Style Transfer in 2021

Tags: computer-vision, neural-style-transfer

I would like to perform the task described in *[A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576v2.pdf)* which applies the style of an image to a different image. This paper dates back to 2015 and there has been a lot of progress in the field of computer vision since then. What is the most up-to-date paper/github repository for this task? I have searched on paperswithcode, but there are no benchmarks or ranking of papers related to the task of style transfer.

Answer (score 2):

[Tensorflowhub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub) has powerful style transfer models such as DeepDream. I think these [models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer) are what you are looking for.